# What's the regex for repeating characters?

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a password strength checker in PHP, and I'm using Regular Expressions to calculate various parameters for the strength calculation.  I need to be able to check the number of repeating consecutive characters in a string.  For example:

`baaabaaablacksheep` would return `5`

`sillystring` would return `1`

```
and so on...
```

Comment: Why 5 and 1? Shouldn't it be 3 and 2?

Comment: @nhahtdh That's what I thought at first too. I think it's 2 for the first set of `a`, 2 for the second set of `a`, and 1 more for the two `e` at the end. Still weird though...

Comment: I don't know that you can do it with regex. Is that required? It would be easy enough to step through the string and count

Comment: I don't think regex is what you are looking for. You would probably need to write a custom function to do this (or Google and find one that someone has already written).

Comment: Perhaps you should read this first: http://www.cafewebmaster.com/check-password-strength-safety-php-and-regex/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex with `\1+` to find the repeating characters, and then use `strlen()` to count them. Try something like:

```
$str = 'baaabaaablacksheep';    
$repeating = array();
preg_match_all('/(\w)(\1+)/', $str, $repeating);

if (count($repeating[0]) > 0) {
    // there are repeating characters
    foreach ($repeating[0] as $repeat) {
        echo $repeat . ' = ' . strlen($repeat) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
aaa = 3
aaa = 3
ee = 2
```

Comment: And how could you use this to get the values he needs (5 for 'baab...')?

Comment: @bjornson The output array, `$repeating`, has a list of all repeating characters in the given string. He can use the values to count them however he needs to - whether it be counting individual character groups, or by adding them all into a single value. Adding them can be done just as easily as the `echo` outputs them: `$value += (strlen($repeat) - 1);`.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant of the solution posted by [newfurniturey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11634469/170194):

```
$passarr = Array('baaabaaablacksheep', 'okstring', 'sillystring');

foreach($passarr as $p) {
   $repeats = 0;
   preg_match_all('/(.)(\1+)/', $p, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
   foreach($matches as $m) $repeats += strlen($m[2]);
   printf("%s => %d repeats\n", $p, $repeats);
}
```

prints:

```
baaabaaablacksheep => 5 repeats
okstring => 0 repeats
sillystring => 1 repeats
```